# Who can access to method with @PermitAll annotation

Tags: java, security, jpa, annotations

Framework (spring + jpa + ejb3 + hiberrnate + jboss5 + jaas)

I want to know, if a method on EJB3, have @PermitAll(javax.annotation.security.PermitAll)  annotation is accessible only by roles defined on application security constraint or is accesible by all roles of all applications deployed at server too.

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means **any one** (even without any role) can access those methods. So your second option is right (by all roles of all applications deployed at server too.)

Comment: If class is annotated with @DeclaredRoles(......) and method with @PermitAll can access this method all roles even without any role too?